# Formatação de número

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber se poderiam me ajudar com a formatação do número impresso.

Erro:

> Quantidade_dia.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: num.toFixed is not a function

Como está saindo: `12.0`

Gostaria que mostrasse somente o `12`

```js
$(document).ready(function teste(){
 $('#tabela').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
    $.ajax({
  type:'post',  //Definimos o método HTTP usado
  dataType: 'json', //Definimos o tipo de retorno
  url: 'quantidade_dia_tele.php',//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
  success: function montaTabela(dados){
            for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
                // formatacao da data
                var dataform = new Date(dados[i].data);
                var dia = dataform.getDate();
                var mes = dataform.getMonth();
                var ano = dataform.getFullYear();
                dataform = dia + '/' + (mes+01) + '/' + ano;
                //formatacao da quantidade
                var num = dados[i].quantidade;
                var numform = num.toFixed();
                console.log(numform);
    //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela
    $('#tabela').append('<tr><td>'+dados[i].id+'</td><td>'+dados[i].nome+'</td><td>'+dados[i].quantidade+'</td><td>'+dataform+'</td></tr>');
   }

   
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

O `.toFixed()` só funciona em dado do tipo número. O valor em `dados[i].quantidade` provavelmente é um número em forma de string, por isso gera o erro citado.

Neste caso você deve converter a string em número. Você pode adicionar um sinal de `+` antes de `dados[i].quantidade` para converter a string em número. Exemplo:

```js
var dados = [
   {
      quantidade: "12.0"
   }
]
for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
   var num = +dados[i].quantidade;
   var numform = num.toFixed();
   console.log(numform);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

var number = 12.0;

var intnumber = Math.floor(number);

alert(number);

</script>
```